# Two machines with Excel 2021 (Office 2021 LTSC) - one refuses to Sum a column of numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel

Have 2 machines with the following specs:

Machine 1: Windows 10 Professional x64 & MS Office LTSC Standard 2021
Machine 2: Windows 11 Professional x64 & MS Office LTSC Professional Plus 2021

Both have the same, identical Build version of Office.

One machine (2) refuses to Autosum/Sum a column of numbers from the same bank download link, while the other (1) has no trouble with same download file, same column, same numbers.

The spreadsheet comes from a bank merchant processor, daily transactions and appear with a leading $dollar sign, like $70.

Have moved manually file between the 2 machines, same issue, unable to Sum on Machine 2. It appears it thinks data is text or something.

Confusing.

Comment: Can you please provide what error it is showing? Also, if you are able to provide the spreadsheet that could help us find anything unusual. Redact anything that could be sensitive though.

Comment: https://postimg.cc/0bj0T2Xn

Comment: $70.00
$70.00
$70.00
$145.00
$70.00
$145.00

Comment: Office is same, version 2108 (Build 14332.20255), where W10Pro is 2021 LTSC Standard (and Sum of the column works fine) and W11Pro is 2021 LTSC Pro Plus where it can not Sum the same column

Comment: Sorry, the picture is unclear. Please show it throwing the error so that we can figure out what is happening. Errors usually look like `#ERR!` or something similar.

Comment: open this image, it shows large jpg in firefox, vivaldi, chrome, opera https://postimg.cc/0bj0T2Xn

Comment: no error shows, no sum either at bottom of 6 rows

Comment: Have you tried summing it yourself? What exactly have you tried? Your picture doesn't really help since I don't see what is happening in the bottom cell. Are you also unable to provide the sheet?

Comment: Nothing happens in the bottom cell on machine 2. that is the problem. normally selecting 6 rows and Sum or Autosum would place total in row 7 for this small example.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UdY0xOUFKeWuDhKABypz7Ngj8BGKPQWC/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=112658971639308327074&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135129/discussion-between-david-tan-and-rosa).

Answer (score 0):

For this to happen, with the same file being independently opened on each machine with no modification (even the act of saving) to it in between openings, the key has to be the currency markers.

When importing anything Excel can interpret as a number, Excel looks to Windows for whether the "likely" number matches one of the patterns in the machine's Windows number and date settings.

If it matches one, and in this case, the key element would be the `$` marker, then it thinks it is looking at a number and imports it as such, and as it has not formatted it as text, it will continue to treat it as a number in ALL its uses of the imported value.

If it does not match one, as in, say, the machine that does not sum has a currency setting of Euros or Yen, then it believes the potential number is actually text. It will treat it as such in many cases. "Many" because sometimes you will use a value that shows as text (left justified being the biggest clue) but is actually just numeric (or related) characters in some way that Excel cannot regard as anything other than you wanting to use the values as numbers. Since they ARE numbers, it does so. This leads to confusion when a different use does allow Excel to consider that they COULD be meant as text, that being a number is not the only possibility, and it then fails that operation if text causes failures.

In this case, I am saying the "good" machine has a Windows settings for currency that uses Dollars. So Excel sees a dollar sign followed immediately (or proximately sometimes) by only numeric or related characters and imports it as a number. It then formats that number (usually/often) as currency, using said Dollar sign, showing pretty much as your image shows. And is happy to successfully sum those values.

On the "bad" machine then, with a different currency in the Windows settings, it sees the same thing, but that Dollar sign is NOT interpreted as "or related characters" and so the whole string/field is seen as text. It is brought in as text with the Dollar sign text character included. When summing the values, they each have a value of zero as any other text character would, so summing adds those up and results in zero. Or possibly an error in an earlier version, which I do remember as I liked to sum columns to include the heading so that my formulas would not get broken by deleting the top data row. And would get errors.

Clearly then, my suggestion is to look at the Windows number/date settings on the machine that is failing to sum, and adjust as needed. That adjustment could even be done just prior to import, then changed back immediately after import.

If that would make for a bigger problem for whatever reason, an alternative would be to remove the `$` characters before or during import. Even after import, though there's a teensy can of worms in that which many just won't deal with so it leads to more aggravation and failure.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change regional/language from Eng/EU to Eng/US

After that, both W10Pro/W11Pro with same build # of MS Off2021LTSC work the same way using the same file.